# Is there a pdfLaTeX binary I can ship with my software?

Tags: portability

I want to create a piece of software which outputs (beautiful) pdfs. However, I don't want to make the user install a LaTeX distribution.

Is there some kind of portable binary I can ship with my application which preferably does not save files on the pc?

Comment: Latex is not a standalone application. There is the binary typesetter (etex), then there is the latex format, packages and fonts. If your application uses latex for processing, you'll need a latex distribution along with it.

Comment: Can't I ship any used packages and required binaries along with it?

Comment: Sure, but you'll need to know exactly which binaries and files are needed. Most people do not, so easier to use an entire latex installation, perhaps starting with one of the minimal ones, and then adding the stuff that you needed

Comment: But my question is if it is possible to ship a distribution/binaries along with my application so no installation is needed.

Comment: In theory it should not be a problem, as long as you have PATHs under control in your application. For example, calling pdflatex with a full path to pdflatex will not always work as it may need to call kpsewhich or other aux binaries which it cannot find. But if they are in the PATH once your application calls pdflatex, it should not be an issue.

Comment: I hope that pdflatex can find the executables when they are in the same folder.

Comment: You probably do not want to compile your tex file in the same folder as the executables, that will just end up being messy.

Comment: A minimal working pdfLaTeX install is nominally only 100s of MB not 1000s it is only #0 000 files instead of #00 000 in a couple of thousand folders In short quality requires a resource overhead So even a portable install will not be "1" binary how many fonts will there be each point size can require multiple files for each style such as bold or italic for pdfLaTeX without all the other TeX there are smaller possibilities but still need thousands of files specially separated into structured folders